# Адаптировать поведение элемента ::after - белая часть рамки остается на границе с фоном

Tags: html, css

[image: Белая часть рамки остается на границе с фоном]

Проблема в следующем: необходимо что бы белая часть рамки оставалась на границе с изображением(адаптивно).

```css
.shoes_banner {
  min-height: 239px;
  margin-top: 29px;
  padding-top: 22px;
  background: url(image/shoes_banner.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 98%;
}

.shoes_banner div {
  width: 47.5%;
  height: 142px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border: 6px solid #01c5c4;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.shoes_banner div::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  width: 15.5%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  border-top: 6px solid #fffeff;
  border-right: 6px solid #fffeff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fffeff;
}
```

```html
<div class="shoes_banner">
  <div>
    <h4>NEW ITEM'S</h4>
    <h3>SHOES COLLECTION</h3>
    <p>Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке.</p>
    <a href="" class="shopping">SHOPPING NOW<i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только как например, задать "резиновую" ширину колонок, но сдвиг задать фиксированным, соответственно и белая рамка с фиксированной шириной:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.shoes_banner {
  min-height: 240px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shoes_banner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512640122685-e77ab16ad8c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) center no-repeat;
  
  background-size: cover;
}

.shoes_banner div {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 142px;
  
  border: 6px solid #01c5c4;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

.shoes_banner div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: 94px;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="shoes_banner">
  <div>
    <h4>NEW ITEM'S</h4>
    <h3>SHOES COLLECTION</h3>
    <p>Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке.</p>
    <a href="" class="shopping">SHOPPING NOW<i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```